# error CS1514: Unexpected symbol `public', expecting `.' or `{'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Good morning guys! I am beginner in C# and game development, so dont swear me))) 
So I have a code, but I have 1 error in 5-th line. Please help me I have tried almost everything,but doesnt help. Hope you'll help me. Thanks))
Error: `PostProcessingController.cs(5,6): error CS1514: Unexpected symbol public', expecting .' or {'`
I Dont know C# well, you are my single hope!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
namespace UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing

public class PostProcessingController : MonoBehaviour \\<--ERROR IN HERE 
{
    public PostProcessVolume Volume;
    public DepthOfFieldSettings DofSettings;

    public ColorGradingSettings ColorSettings;

    DepthOfField dof;
    ColorGrading colorGrading;

    void Start()
    {
        Volume.sharedProfile = Instantiate(Volume.sharedProfile);

        dof = Volume.profile.GetSetting<DepthOfField>();
        colorGrading = Volume.profile.GetSetting<ColorGrading>();

        DofSettings.focusDistance = dof.focusDistance.value;
        DofSettings.aperture = dof.aperture.value;
        DofSettings.focalLength = dof.focalLength.value;

        ColorSettings.Lift = colorGrading.lift.value;
        ColorSettings.GreenOutGreenIn = colorGrading.mixerGreenOutGreenIn.value;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        dof.focusDistance.value = DofSettings.focusDistance;
        dof.aperture.value = DofSettings.aperture;
        dof.focalLength.value = DofSettings.focalLength;

        colorGrading.lift.value = ColorSettings.Lift;
        colorGrading.mixerGreenOutGreenIn.value = ColorSettings.GreenOutGreenIn;
    }

    public void LerpDof(DepthOfFieldSettings start, DepthOfFieldSettings end, float t)
    {
        DofSettings.focusDistance = Mathf.Lerp(start.focusDistance, end.focusDistance, t);
        DofSettings.aperture = Mathf.Lerp(start.aperture, end.aperture, t);
        DofSettings.focalLength = Mathf.Lerp(start.focalLength, end.focalLength, t);
    }

    public void LerpColorGrading(ColorGradingSettings start, ColorGradingSettings end, float t)
    {
        ColorSettings.Lift = Vector4.Lerp(start.Lift, end.Lift, t);
        ColorSettings.GreenOutGreenIn = Mathf.Lerp(start.GreenOutGreenIn, end.GreenOutGreenIn, t);
    }

    [ContextMenu("Show grading")]
    void showLift()
    {
        colorGrading = Volume.profile.GetSetting<ColorGrading>();
        Debug.Log(colorGrading.lift.value);
        Debug.Log(colorGrading.mixerGreenOutGreenIn.value);
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public struct DepthOfFieldSettings
    {
        public float focusDistance;
        public float aperture;
        public float focalLength;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public struct ColorGradingSettings
    {
        public Vector4 Lift;
        public float GreenOutGreenIn;
    }
}
```

Comment: missing `{` after `namespace UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing` and probably `}` at the end too

Comment: Doesnt work(( I tried but there was 9 errors like:

Comment: The type or namespace name `PostProcessingController' could not be found. Are you missing `UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing' using directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `namespace` by `using` and add `;` at the end of the line

```
using UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing;
```

you will also need the [PostPrecessing Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.1/manual/index.html) imported via the [PackageManager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.package-manager-ui@1.8/manual/index.html)

(Here is a [List of all available Packages](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PackagesList.html))